# Shell Script to create pdf from asciidoc

Tags: linux, shell

I'm new to linux and want to create a pdf from an asciidoc using a toolchain.

Running

```
a2x -fpdf -dbook --fop essayv1.txt
```

in the shell works fine.
I wanted to write a script to automate that, so I wrote this and put it into create.sh:

```
myfile="/media/essay/essayv1"
rm -f ${myfile}.pdf
a2x -fpdf -dbook --fop ${myfile}.txt
```

However, running this via sh create.sh only gives me

```
.txt ERROR: missing SOURCE_FILE: /media/essay/essayv1
```

Can someone tell me how to fix that simple script?

Comment: Did you edit this script with an editor that put Windows line-endings in it? Run `dos2unix` or similar on your `create.sh`.

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution. As simple as that and I've wasted hours trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
#!/bin/sh
myfile="/media/essay/essayv1"
cd `dirname "${myfile}.txt"`
rm -f ${myfile}.pdf
a2x -fpdf -dbook --fop "${myfile}.txt"
```

Comment: Got the same error as before, now in addition `create.sh: 3: cd: can't cd to /media/essay`

Typing `cd /media/essay` into the shell works, though

Comment: Directory `/media/essay` exist ? And the file `/media/essay/essayv1.txt` exist ?

Comment: Definitely, I can access them via normal shell commands.
I may add that this Ubuntu is running in VirtualBox and "essay" is a folder shared with the Windows host machine, but I assumed that would make no difference for handling the files in it.